# Python: how can i find minimum and maximum values in subarrays elements?

Tags: python

I've the following array:

```
[[499, 3], [502, 3], [502, 353], [499, 353]]
```

They are the verteces of a rectangle.

I need to find the top-left, top-right, bottom-left and bottom-right vertex.

What's the best python code to do it ?

thanks

Comment: @systempuntoout what's wrong ? Isn't an array ?

Comment: In Python you should call that data structure a [list](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html) ; there are other modules that provide array objects ( [array](http://docs.python.org/library/array.html) and [numpy](http://www.scipy.org/Tentative_NumPy_Tutorial))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**edit**: thanks to tokand for pointing out that this can be done with tuple unpacking.

you could sort it.

```
(bottomleft, bottomright,topleft, topright) = sorted(vertices)
```

or you could do it in place with

```
corners.sort()
(bottomleft, bottomright,topleft, topright) = corners
# the unpacking here is redundant but demonstrative
```

For reference, the output of sorted is:

```
>>> a = [[499, 3], [502, 3], [502, 353], [499, 353]]
>>> sorted(a)
[[499, 3], [499, 353], [502, 3], [502, 353]]
>>>
```

This will be O(nlogn) whereas there are surely O(n) solutions available. But for a list of this size, I don't think it's a biggy unless you have a ton of them, (in which case, the speed of the native C implementation will outperform a custom python function anyways so it's still optimal from a practical perspective.)

Comment: the same idea with tuple unpacking: topleft, topright, bottomleft, bottomright = sorted(vertices)

Comment: @tokland, good idea. I was just getting the point across I guess. That's probably how i'd actually write it.

Answer (score 0):

```
vertices = [[499, 3], [499, 353], [502, 3], [502, 353]]

# if the origin is the top left
(topleft, bottomleft, topright, bottomright) = sorted(vertices)

# if the origin is the bottom left
(bottomleft, topleft, bottomright, topright) = sorted(vertices)
```